# Elimination mechanism in alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereoselectivity, elimination

Do E2 elimination reactions occur in alkenes? If not, what mechanism is used?

If they do, are they limited by any stereochemical rules as alkanes do (antiperiplanar)?

My question is pernitent to the alkyne reaction mechanism, where both the E and Z alkenes undergo elimination to form the alkyne.[image]

My guess is E2 mechanism is possible for the Z alkene, while the E alkene undergoes E1

Answer (score 4):

No E<sub>1</sub>elimination. E<sub>2</sub> in both cases. The E-isomer has a good overlap; syn elimination. The Z-isomer goes through anti elimination.

Comment: Thank you. I am guessing no E1 due to the instability of a vinylic carbocation
But I have never heard of syn elimination before
Are there any resources you'd recommend?

Comment: You are right about the carbocation. For syn elimination in vinyl halides, See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23966/why-can-syn-periplanar-e2-elimination-happen-in-molecules-like-vinyl-bromides-bu